# Is there a common origin to those blue background TV commercials?

Tags: analysis, production, commercial

I've seen a number of these in my many years of watching TV since at least the 1990s. These are commercials for some random mail order product, and right before the ad ends, the screen cuts to something laid out as follows:

- A solid blue or gradient blue background.
- The price on the upper right, usually in white.
- The phone number (more recently, website) centered, usually in yellow.
- Various fine print at the very bottom centered, in white, sometimes terms and conditions, usually an address.
- Credit card logos directly above or below the price
- The top left has a representative picture of the product, or repeating video from the rest of the ad
- A voice over with someone reading the pertinent info

Here are some examples:
[image: A 1990s music album]
[image: Another one]
[image: A more recent example]

They seem to have been around for a long time.

Is this a trademarked format, or does it have any background other than "something a bunch of advertisers decided to use"?

There does not seem to be any commonality between the companies and types of products that use it.

Comment: Color Psychology, and Color Marketing.

Comment: Wow! Haven't seen one of those since the 70's or 80's. Do they still do that in some places? It became pretty much a meme in the UK that no-one would ever buy anything from an ad that ended like that, so they stopped doing them.

Comment: Yeah actually. That last one hawking coins has been around since at least 2012. I just saw it a couple hours ago.

Comment: related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50932/on-tv-when-you-see-an-infomercial-why-do-they-use-jarring-colors

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ad people know how to push our buttons.

Psychological analysis on the impact of color shows that people (i.e. consumers) associate blue with concepts such as [credibility, being business-like, professionalism, and trust](https://blog.bufferapp.com/the-science-of-colors-in-marketing-why-is-facebook-blue).

IBM was proud to be called "Big Blue." Facebook isn't blue by chance.

Blue is also [associated with honesty](http://www.empower-yourself-with-color-psychology.com/blue-in-business.html).

All of these are good associations to create when you are trying to separate people from their money.

Comment: I want to accept this one, but is it really that simple? Everyone just decided to use a nearly identical template for the end of their ads?

Comment: Sad, isn't it. But when you don't have much money to spend on your ad, and there's a format out there that works, why take the risk.